# Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassofEmployees
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
     class employee
    { //will include the attributes of all employees of your organization.

        //fields for employee
      public int employeeId; // 5 digit number to represent employee
      public int ssn; //social security number of employee
      public string name; //employee name
      public int dob; //date of birth
      public int pay; //rate of pay


    }

    class managers : employee
    {
        public string backgroundCheck {get; set;}
        public string isSalary;
        public string responsibilitys;



    }
    private void getEmployeeData(employee employee)
    {

        employee.employeeId = int.Parse(EmployeeID.Text);
        employee.ssn = int.Parse(SSN.Text);
        employee.name = employeeName.Text;
        employee.dob = int.Parse(DOB.Text);
        employee.pay = int.Parse(pay.Text);
        managers.backgroundCheck = bCYes;
        managers.isSalary = salaryYes;
        managers.responsibilitys = responsibilitys.Text;
    }

    private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create new employee object
        employee newemployee = new employee();
        //get employee data
        getEmployeeData(newemployee);
        //add employee data to new form window list
    }
```

Okay I am completely lost on the error I am receiving. I am following an example in my text book.

This is the error I receive:

Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ClassofEmployees.Form1.managers.BCY.get' C:\Users\T-Ali\Desktop\SHawnasschool\vb.net 2 c#\projects\ClassofEmployees\ClassofEmployees\Form1.cs    59  13  ClassofEmployees

What I understand is that the object is not created. However The object I believe I created with this line of code:

```
 //create new employee object
        employee newemployee = new employee();
        //get employee data
        getEmployeeData(newemployee);
        //add employee data to new form window list
```

why does employee.name or any of the employee.something work, but the manager part wont? how can I fix this?

Comment: The error suggests your `managers` class has a property called `BCY`, but this doesn't appear in your question. Are you sure this is the exact code that results in the error?

Comment: I am sorry, I had changed the code in hopes that it would fix the problem but it didn't and I forgot to change it back, I have edited my post and fixed the code to exactly like I have it with the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're reading non-static fields from the `manager` class.

```
managers.backgroundCheck = bCYes;
managers.isSalary = salaryYes;
managers.responsibilitys = responsibilitys.Text;
```

`managers` is a class, not an object instance. You need to create a new manager object like you did with the employee.

Comment: `getEmployeeData` is an instance member of `Form1`, not `employee`.

Comment: @lee - Yes, you're right. Got slightly mixed up trying to read through it. It seems the issue is with using the `managers` class in a static manner.

Comment: keyboard thank you so very much!! I created a new manager object and everything is flowing now!

Comment: Keyboard if I created the classes like this                    class employee : manager   class manager                     would that allow me to skip creating the new manager object? Basically flipping the inheritance portion.

Comment: It's because the parent class is `employee` and the child class is `manager`. Therefore the manager class will have the employee properties, and its own, but the employee class will only have its own. Think of it like this. You have a parent class called `Vehicle` and a child class called `Car`. Just because the Car has a `Wheels` property doesn't mean all `Vehicles` have wheels. That's why the parent class (`employee` in this case) has properties common to all employees. Anything that inherits from it, like `manager`, can then add its own particular properties.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you for that further clarification and example, now I understand!